# Postgres need to get count of rows by uniqueness

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table that has lat, long, and time. Basically, I want the result of my query to give me something like this:

`lat,long,hourwindow,count`

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried so many things I can't keep them straight. And unfortunately Here's what I've got so far:

```
WITH all_lat_long_by_time AS (
    SELECT
      trunc(cast(lat AS NUMERIC), 4) AS lat,
      trunc(cast(long AS NUMERIC), 4) AS long,
      date_trunc('hour', time :: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) AS hourWindow

    FROM my_table
),
    unique_lat_long_by_time AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT * FROM all_lat_long_by_time
  ),
  all_with_counts AS (
   -- what do I do here?
  )
SELECT * FROM all_with_counts;
```

Comment: Please explain how "count of rows by uniqueness" is defined exactly. Do you mean a count of unique rows (after truncating numbers)? So the number of distinct `(lat, long)` per hour? Postgres version and table definition are always helpful, too. `time :: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty basic aggregation query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time :: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE) AS hourWindow
       trunc(cast(lat AS NUMERIC), 4) AS lat,
       trunc(cast(long AS NUMERIC), 4) AS long,
       COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY hourWindow, trunc(cast(lat AS NUMERIC), 4), trunc(cast(long AS NUMERIC), 4)
ORDER BY hourWindow
```

Comment: Ha, when you stare at a problem space for so long that you forget how to SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If "count of rows by uniqueness" is meant to count *distinct* coordinates per hour (after truncating the numbers), `count(DISTINCT (lat,long))` does the job:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time::timestamp) AS hour_window
     , count(DISTINCT (trunc( lat::numeric, 4)
                     , trunc(long::numeric, 4))) AS count_distinct_coordinates
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).
`(lat,long)` is a ROW value and short for `ROW(lat,long)`. More [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).

But `count(DISTINCT ...)` is typically slow, a subquery should be faster for your case:

```
SELECT hour_window, count(*) AS count_distinct_coordinates
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('hour', time::timestamp) AS hour_window
        , trunc( lat::numeric, 4) AS lat
        , trunc(long::numeric, 4) AS long
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT hour_window, count(*) AS count_distinct_coordinates
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          date_trunc('hour', time::timestamp) AS hour_window
        , trunc( lat::numeric, 4) AS lat
        , trunc(long::numeric, 4) AS long
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

After the subquery folds duplicates, the outer `SELECT` can use a plain `count(*)`.